# algorithmic complexity of reducibility

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Is there an algorthm for determining if a finite dimentional complex representation of a finite group is reducible? If so are there estimates for time and space requiremnts? What about quantum algorithms.

Comment: Just take the inner product of the character with itself and see whether it is 1. 

Answer (score 1):

@Benjamin's algorithm works, but if the representation is given by images of the generators, this will be exponential time in the size of the input (if you are actually given the images of all the elements, you might as well compute the traces, of course). In that case, you are just seeing if the relevant matrices are simultaneously block-diagonalizable, which is simple linear algebra, but since you are looking to solve the problem exactly, the complexity is going to be something like the dimension of the representation to the fifth. I have no idea how much quantum computation helps, but I am sure there is a million papers on quantum linear algebra algorithms.